# Get an XML Element value from a DTSX File Using an XML Parser

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis, xml-parsing, etl

The dtsx (SSIS package file) is an Xml file. it contains an element named `PackageFormatVersion` (Which version of SSDT are related to this package)

```
 <DTS:Property
DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
```

I have written a Vb.net script to retrieve this element value using `RegEx` using the following expression *(and it is working fine)*

```
  Dim strA As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=""PackageFormatVersion"">)(.*)(?=</DTS:Property>)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
```

But i think that the recommended way to achieve this is by using an `XML Parser`, the way that i didn't know how to achieve it. Any Help?

**I accept answers in C#**

Package Xml Looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
 DTS:refId="Package"
 DTS:CreationDate="3/26/2017 11:44:38 PM"
 DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
 DTS:CreatorComputerName="MyComputer"
 DTS:CreatorName="MyComputer\Admin"
 DTS:DTSID="{384605BC-FC77-4506-B409-C1EE9B21BAE2}"
 DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
 DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="13.0.4001.0"
 DTS:LocaleID="1033"
 DTS:ObjectName="Package"
 DTS:PackageType="5"
 DTS:VersionBuild="2"
 DTS:VersionGUID="{66D08BFA-6426-4123-99F7-6E655B79AF6D}">
 <DTS:Property
 DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
 <DTS:ConnectionManagers>
 <DTS:ConnectionManager ...
```

Comment: Why is using an XML Parser the 'recommended way'? I like what you've done. A regex is fast, straightforward, and does not require detailed parsing of the nested structure of the full XML document. If you go the XML Parser way, you will bind yourself to the near exact schema of the DTS package (which can change from version to version). While it's true that the property you are after currently exists in the top-level node, regex still may be a more lean and faster approach. Keep your actual requirements in mind and let the best solution for those reqs win out. </MyOpinion>

Comment: @ryancdotnet regex will fail if a new attribute is added to the element, or if a white space , line feed is added. While xml parsers can search for a specific tag by it's name. Then get it's value. Also regex may fails the ssis contains a variable named `PackageFormatVersion` (users may not know about this property and use this name as a variable). Also i think that when it is all about well structured data regex is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

```
Dim strA As String = ""

Dim xml = XDocument.Load(strFile)

Dim ns As XNamespace = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
Dim man As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
man.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")

If Not xml.Root Is Nothing AndAlso
   Not xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name") Is Nothing AndAlso
   xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name").Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PackageFormatVersion").Count > 0 Then

   strA = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name").Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PackageFormatVersion").FirstOrDefault.Parent.Value


End If

Msgbox(strA)
```

i started from this question [Parse SSIS .xml source to retrieve table mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513566/parse-ssis-xml-source-to-retrieve-table-mappings)